# Default option in select tag not working in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this issue:
in Controller:

```
$countries=mytable::lists('country');
return view('myview', ['countries'=>$countries]);
```

In view:

```
{!!Form::select('Country', $countries, $item->Country)!!}
```

`$item->Country` is the `country` of the `user` and it should be the default option already selected. However, what I get is the list of countries in alphabetical order... as it comes from the database.
My question is what am I doing wrong? Why the select tag doesn't get the default option ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{!! Form::select('Country', $countries, $item->Country, []) !!}
```

The select input is looking for 4 parameters

1. The name of the input
2. The values
3. The selected value
4. And an array of other attributes (class, id etc)

What is more, I hope you know, that this only gives you an array of the country names.

```
$countries = mytable::lists('country')
```

`$item->Country` probably gives you a name of the country, whereas the select input has values of 0, 1, 2, 3 and the texts are the names of the countries. So there there isn't a value of a country's name in the select input.

You should edit your question and add the description of `mytable` so that we'd know how to help you.

Comment: It works now... but the form doesn't  send the country name, but the rank in the table. So if the country is Cuba and is the 50th in the table, it sends 50 not Cuba...  now I'm missing something else...

Comment: You could do `$countries=mytable::lists('country', 'country');`

Answer (score 1):

As i think, $item->country is an object, you shoud set the id itself

```
{!!Form::select('Country', $countries, $item->Country->id)!!}
```

Also in your controller, add `id` as a key to the collection:

```
$countries=mytable::lists('country', 'id');
```